# Can i make my regex shortest?

Tags: regex

Is there any better(shortest) regex then the below which matches the below conditions?

```
/((.*,)|\s*)String((,.*)|\s*)/
```

Conditions:

--> Should select only when there is the exact match for the string (String might be in comma separated list or just the only String)
few accepted cases is for inputs:

```
String, some other, something other
some other, String
String
```

Example inputs for failure:

```
String test,String new,Stringtest
```

The problem is after encoding the url length will be increased because of this big regex. So i am thinking if there is a way to make my regex better to match the conditions.

Comment: It is not clear from your examples what you need. Maybe you just want to match `String` as a whole word? `/\bString\b/`?

Comment: I have updated the condition. Actually its should check in a comma seperated list or the string might be the only element in the list. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your suggestion will also include the text like "String Text"

Comment: Probably [`(^|,\s*)String($|\s*,)`](https://regex101.com/r/GBcKr1/1) will work then. I see you may have spaces after and before commas.

Comment: looks good can you please post it as answer. Will accept this. Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(^|,\s*)String($|\s*,)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GBcKr1/1).

**Details**

- `(^|,\s*)` - either the start of string (`^`) or (`|`) a comma followed with  0+ whitespace chars
- `String` - a literal `String`
- `($|\s*,)` - either the end of string (`$`) or (`|`) 0+ whitespace chars followed with a comma.